# Reconstructing nested Observables

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

This is a beginner's question. I am streaming back the output of several processes back to client, and I want to store each stream to a separate file.

So what I want is (large letter indicates the end of the nested stream)

```
S: -a-a-a-b-b-a-A-c-b-B-c-c-...-d--C...D-e--...-z-E-z--z--...

R:  a-a-a-----a-A (complete)
          b-b-------b-B (complete)
                  c-----c-c--------C (complete)
                                d------D (complete)
                                         e--------E (complete)

                     .
                     .
                     . 
       (end many more nested streams coming)
                     .
```

So I want something like a dynamic factory of Observables. Similar to `using()`, but as I understand `using()` creates Observables that exist as long as the original Observable, whereas I want to complete and close file every time nested stream completes.

IMPORTANT - I don't want to buffer in memory, as these are very long streams (output of long running processes). So I would like to avoid `buffer()`, `groupBy()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can determine from a value if it is the final for a particular letter, you can use `groupBy` with `takeUntil` in the inner groups (you may need a few try-catches in the lambdas):

```
source
.groupBy(v -> v.type)
.flatMap(g -> 
     Observable.using(
         () -> createOutput(g.getKey()), 
         f -> g.takeUntil(v -> v.isEnd).doOnNext(v -> f.write(v))),
         f -> f.close()
     )
)
.subscribe(...)
```

`TakeUntil` makes sure `groupBy` only keeps sub-streams as long as we expect values of it (and if the source is properly ordered, `groupBy` won't recreate the group).

If you really want to avoid `groupBy`, you have to manually track each open file and close them at the appropriate times:

```
Observable.using(
    HashMap::new,
    map -> source
       .doOnNext(v -> {
           Output o = map.get(v.type);
           if (o == null) {
               o = new Output(v.type);
               map.put(v.type, o);
           }
           o.write(v);
           if (v.isEnd) {
               o.close();
               map.remove(v.type);
           }
       }),
    map -> map.values().forEach(e -> e.close())
)
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I am looking at the second part (because I really don't want to use `groupBy()`) It looks like working, but this does not seem to be a reactive solution. It is just a listener, that dispatches data based on its private hashmap. So it is a standard imperative way. Is there a way to solve the problem in a pure reactive way?

Comment: Option #1 is more reactive and if you can get a hold on a reactive file library, you can go full async in saving as well. Otherwise, don't be afraid in mixing the two concepts if that solves your problem more efficiently.

Comment: It is not fear. Simply I would like to learn how to write a proper reactive code. And same as I am not trying to inline assembler when writing java code (not sure if this is even possible), I don't want to inject non-reactive techniques into reactive code. Option #1 is reactive without any doubts, but it accumulates data in memory. It is something I cannot do, as already explained in the original question.

Comment: It retains the references to the groups but not the items. Going reactive and functional usually incurs more memory usage and data retention which is opposite what you need.

Comment: This is true that functional incurs more memory usage, reactive though, aims to ease the creation of event-driven systems, which are supposed to be lighter and suitable for processing very longs streams of events. That's why for instance Rx is single-threaded by default. So my use case seems to be a perfect fit for reactive. Please help me to understand "It retains the references to the groups but not the items.".  As I understand your Option #1 code, if I have 100 unfinished streams of 1GB each, I have 100 GBs in memory. Is it correct?

Comment: If your source stream supports backpressure, you'll have at most 128.000 items in memory if you have an async boundary at each group. If there is no asynchrony, each group will act as a pass-through and other than holding a reference to 100 GroupedObservable instance, none of the values will stay in memory. If you have a hot source and an async boundary, the sequence will most likely fail with backpressure error before reaching a couple of GB memory usage.

Comment: Very interesting. I need to read more about that. But it sounds like relying on safety nets. It might work in most cases, but if they fail ("the sequence will most likely fail with backpressure error") I have a problem. Is there really no clean solution to this problem?